# Why socket.io listener in android side not called?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, kotlin, socket.io

I write socket middleware for user Authentication but I don't know what's my problem!
in android side **"unauthorized"** event not called.

Server-side :

```
async function (socket, next) {

    
    if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token) {
        jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, process.env.SECRET_JWT_KEY, function (err, decoded) {

            if (err) {
                socket.emit( "unauthorized",  "unauthorized user") <==send to sender you'r authentication is failed 
                console.log("Query: ", "unauthorized");    <==This line is lunched
                return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
            }
            socket.decoded = decoded;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }
```

Client-side :

```
   val socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.6:3000", IO.Options().apply {
                path = "/sockets/chat"
                query = "token=wrongtoken"
            })

  socket.on("unauthorized", object : Emitter.Listener { <== THIS NOT LUNCED!!
                override fun call(vararg args: Any?) {
                  println("user authentication failed" )
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution no need to emit from middleware when throwing an error you can get predefined events in an android client like this:

```
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR) { args -> println(args.contentToString()) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to connect to the socket first by calling this line inside apply block

```
this.connect()
```

Comment: apply block is for "Options". however i'll tried `socket.connect()`